# How to create module in javascript

Tags: javascript

**As I am new to javascript, and i got a code which explains how module can be created and used but I have problem in figuring out what does the for loop does in the following snippet, So can anybody help me out
in figuring out how the code is working**.

```js
var MyModules = (function Manager() {
    var modules = {};
    function define(name, deps, impl) {
    for (var i=0; i<deps.length; i++) {
    deps[i] = modules[deps[i]];
    }
    modules[name] = impl.apply( impl, deps );
    }
    function get(name) {
    return modules[name];
    }
    return {
    define: define,
    get: get
    };
    })();

 MyModules.define( "bar", [], function(){
function hello(who) {
return "Let me introduce: " + who;
}
return {
hello: hello
};
} );
MyModules.define( "foo", ["bar"], function(bar){
var hungry = "hippo";
function awesome() {
console.log( bar.hello( hungry ).toUpperCase() );
}
return {
awesome: awesome
};
} );
var bar = MyModules.get( "bar" );
var foo = MyModules.get( "foo" );
console.log(
bar.hello( "hippo" )
);
```

Comment: This is not a module, it's a module loader / dependency resolver.

Answer (score 0):

You can read good article explain what are module how you can implement it.
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/javascript-modules-a-beginner-s-guide-783f7d7a5fcc

```
function myModule() {
  this.hello = function() {
     return 'hello!';
  }

   this.goodbye = function() {
     return 'goodbye!';
   }
}

module.exports = myModule;
```

You can you use the above module shown below

```
var myModule = require('myModule');

var myModuleInstance = new myModule();
myModuleInstance.hello(); // 'hello!'
myModuleInstance.goodbye(); // 'goodbye!'
```